# What's the command for going to next jump spot (<Tab> or <C-I> functionality)?

Tags: vim

I am using Tab to toggle window focus via `nnoremap <Tab> :wincmd w<CR>`.

This means I can no longer use `<Tab>` to move forward in the jump list. (Often used in conjunction with `<C-O>` whivh moves backward in jump list)

What is the colon command to jump next, so I can bind this to a less important key than its original key (Tab)?

Comment: what do you mean by jump list ? Autocompletion?

Comment: I don't see any other command in the help for jump other than `<C-I>` and `<tab>`

Comment: @x4vier What editor do you use? It is the equivalent of `Ctrl+U` on Sublime Text. It moves to where you *were*. Helps you remember what the hell you did in a file. @FDinoff, ya that's why I'm here...

Comment: Well... Ctrl+O being the equiv. of Ctrl+U in ST. Dunno if ST lets you do this "jump forward" that `<Tab>` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just remap `<tab>` to something else.

For example you could remap `<Tab>` to `` ` ``

```
nnoremap ` <Tab>
```

This will keep the original functionality of the tab for going forward in the jump list.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<C-i>`, it's more consistent with  than `<Tab>`.

Anyway, `<C-i>` is the same as `<Tab>` so mapping `<Tab>` effectively covers both `<tab>` *and* `<C-i>`. But that's irrelevant.

There's unfortunately no jumplist-related Ex command besides `:jumps` so I'm afraid you'll need to write your own function/command or abandon that mapping.